# SQL query syntax error, negative number not possible?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I receive the following error, the error contains a SQL syntax problem. I would not know what the problem is because everything seems fine. I can see a negative number in $range_start (-4). What would be the problem? Should I add anything at the negative number in the SQL query?

(It's a pagination and it works fine in other SQL queries)

Thanks in advance.

Error:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 42000
    [1] => 1064
    [2] => You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''4'' at line 1
)
```

Code:

```
$getPostsByCategory = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE category = :category ORDER by date_created DESC LIMIT " . $range_start . ", " . $range_end . "");
```

Comment: what is the `category = :category` part? That seems odd to me

Comment: @mituw16 That is PDO escaping.

Comment: Ah I see, I've only used PDO once or twice, usually use mysqli prepared statements. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `LIMIT` keyword specifies that you want a subset of the elements. `$range_start` is the offset, that is, the first index of the result you want, while `$range_end` is the number of elements you want. As a result, both of these need to be positive integers, so `$range_start` cannot be negative, as you cannot load the elements, starting from the -4th.

Comment: Ah, okay. I've changed it to `$getPostsByCategory = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE category = :category ORDER by date_created DESC LIMIT  0, '" . $range_end . "'");` , however, I still get the following error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''4'' at line

Comment: What do you still get? What is the vaue of $range_end?

Comment: The value of range_end is 4.

Comment: You do not need the quote, as 4 is a number. Just use LIMIT 0, 4 at the end of your query.

Comment: It is a bug in my pagination then, I will take a look.

Comment: If that works, then try with LIMIT 0, ".$range_end." and see if it works as well. If not, then you have something with the parameter. If it does not work with LIMIT 0, 4 either, then at least we know that your second problem is not with the limit.

Comment: Please, tell me if your query runs finely with LIMIT 0, 4. If yes, then you just have to fix how those variables are procecced, aka. how you set their values.

Comment: Yes, it works with LIMIT 0, 4 (however, you don't see the posts but I'm sure it is a bug in my paginiation.

Comment: Use echo var_dump("Range Start: ".$range_start.", Range End:".$range_end); to see the values. And you can edit your question with details about your paging. As about the question itself, I believe my answer answered your question about negative offset, so you might consider accepting it as the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Strings need to be encapsulated by either a quote or apostrophe depending on whether your string was constructed with quotes or apostrophes.

In this case, I would recommend the following:

```
'" . $range_start . "', '" . $range_end . "'
```

Note the use of apostrophe's before and after.